# How to substitute the LINQ Query with lambda expression

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, lambda

Lets say that I have generated a List of Arrays and I want to group them accordingly to the remainder by 8. Here is how I do it with LINQ, but I was wondering how to do it by using labmda expression.:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var intArray = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
{
    intArray.Add(rnd.Next(20, 50));
}
var randomLettersSortedAsc =
    from element in intArray
    group element by element % 8 into g
    select g;
```

Answer (score 7):

You only have to apply the [GroupBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) method:

```
var groupedLetters = intArray.GroupBy(item => item % 8);
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks 100 times better than my LINQ.

Comment: @user2128702 these queries are both LINQ. And lambda is even more LINQ (if we can say so), than your query, because LINQ query written in *query syntax* is compiled into *lambda syntax query*. And when compiled, your query will look exactly same way as this lambda-syntax query.